# What does `process_usershare_file` do?

Tags: logs, samba, stat

I have a samba server that is giving me this in logs for every single share (in this case "Public" is the share):

```
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.398065,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/publi failed. Permission denied
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.398688,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/publi failed. No such file or directory
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.400642,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/publi failed. Permission denied
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.401232,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/publi failed. No such file or directory
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.403194,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/publi failed. Permission denied
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.403814,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/publi failed. No such file or directory
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.404843,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/public.bat failed. Permission denied
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.405536,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/public.bat failed. No such file or directory
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.406666,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/public.cmd failed. Permission denied
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.407276,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/public.cmd failed. No such file or directory
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.408284,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/public.exe failed. Permission denied
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.408987,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/public.exe failed. No such file or directory
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.410125,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/public.com failed. Permission denied
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.410716,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/public.com failed. No such file or directory
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.411692,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/public.pif failed. Permission denied
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.412420,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/public.pif failed. No such file or directory
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.413585,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/public.lnk failed. Permission denied
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.414163,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/public.lnk failed. No such file or directory
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.415144,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/public.dll failed. Permission denied
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.415857,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/public.dll failed. No such file or directory
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.418115,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/publi failed. Permission denied
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.418842,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/publi failed. No such file or directory
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.424562,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/publi failed. Permission denied
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.427558,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/publi failed. No such file or directory
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.433017,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/publi failed. Permission denied
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.436073,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/publi failed. No such file or directory
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.441569,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]:   process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/publi failed. Permission denied
Sep  2 07:49:42 MyServer smbd[31606]: [2014/09/02 07:49:42.444667,  0] param/loadparm.c:9114(process_usershare_file)
```

What is `process_usershare_file` supposed to do, and any ideas why it is failing?

Edit:  I am not even using `/var/lib/usershare/` at all.  I do not know why it is looking there.

Comment: Should this be on ServerFault?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short version:

The client machine is using MS Windows with ["Windows Defender"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Defender) enabled.

The scan process is responsible for that logfile spamming...

Verify: Check day and time on the client to run "Windows Defender" scan,
compare with your SAMBA logs.

Comment: This is not entirely correct for me, but it looks like it's on the right lines. I'm running Microsoft Security Essentials rather than Windows Defender, but indeed many of the errors in the logs coincide exactly with the times that Microsoft Security Essentials is running.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Stat man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat):

**Description**

These functions return information about a file. No permissions are required on the file itself, but-in the case of stat() and lstat() - execute (search) permission is required on all of the directories in path that lead to the file.

See also [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide)

I believe you need to set the default permissions.

---

**Answer for Comment**:

> The shares are defined in the background using the "net usershare"
>   command and the definitions are saved in /var/lib/samba/usershares/ .
>   Therefore, shares defined with this method are not visible in
>   smb.conf.

Have you set any shares using the CLI?

Comment: Ummmm... My `/var/lib/usershares` file is empty.  I don't even have my shares there.

Comment: Wait---what? Is this an answer? I have the same problem. What do I do? I am a bit confused about who said what when and what the key comment was. My samba shares seem to work fine on a home network with ubuntu and windows machines, but the windows machines are generating gigantic log files with errors like the one in the original post. What exactly is my problem?